# Will L293D arduino shield lose functionality if I connect it with jumpers instead of mounting on arduino?

Tags: shields, arduino-motor-shield

I'm new to arduino and have bought a L293D motor driver shield which have no heads on the pins. I looked at the pinout and it seems that shield does not use any of the pins "by default". So will it work properly if I connect it like it isn't a shield(without mounting), because I need to use other pins and it would be nice if I don't need to solder them. I know it's some basic stuff but I want to avoid messing up at the very beginning if I don't have to. Thanks.

Comment: As long as you connect all the pins that need to be connected there is no reason the shield has to be mounted on top of the Arduino.

Comment: Thank you for answering, missing headers confused me on this shield.